# Handler remove callback and put again in ACTION_UP

Tags: java, android

I want to call function(close one widget if user didn't touch another view for 10 seconds).
Touchable view has listener like

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int x = (int) event.getX();
    int y = (int) event.getY();
    switch (event.getAction()) {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        if(handler != null){
            handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
            handler = null;
        }
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        if(handler != null){
            handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
            handler = null;
        }
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        startTime = Calendar.getInstance().get(
                        Calendar.MILLISECOND);
                handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        isMenuVisible = false;
                        postInvalidate();
                    }
                }, startTime + EXPANDED_PERIOD);
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I have tried also to have only one member handler and to avoid to create on up. Idea is when user do up action to wait 10 seconds if not touch again and then close.
But it doesn't close. When I remove in ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_MOVE remove it closes even when I touch view. How to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not add startTime in postDelayed()

[Read doc here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29)

use the following code instead.

```
handler.postDelayed(***, EXPANDED_PERIOD);
```